# Calling method from inside Javascript constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a method from inside a Javascript contructor. Here's an example:

```
function team(team_id) {
    this.team_id = team_id;
    init();

    this.init = function () {
        alert('testing this out: ' + this.team_id);
    };
}

var my_team = new team(15);
```

Also: http://jsfiddle.net/N8Rxt/2/

This doesn't work. The alert is never displayed. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place your call to the init() method, underneath the definition.

Also call it using this.init();

```
function team(team_id) {
    this.team_id = team_id;

    this.init = function () {
        alert('testing this out: ' + this.team_id);
    };

    this.init();
}

var my_team = new team(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepending the call to `init()` with `this` and moving it to the end of the object helps:

```
function team(team_id) {
    this.team_id = team_id;

    this.init = function () {
        alert('testing this out: ' + this.team_id);
    };

    this.init();
}

var my_team = new team(15);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N8Rxt/3/